# Moving an object (square) using tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to move a square using WASD keys, with my implementation, I'm having trouble trying to passing arguments in the function update function. I am hoping to make it listen for an event from the keyboard. Can anyone help me?

```
class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.speed = [0, 0]     # iniital speed ste to 0
        self.image = window.create_rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20, fill="white")  # sample robot
        window.bind_all("<KeyPress-w>", self.update)
        window.bind_all("<KeyPress-a>", self.update)
        window.bind_all("<KeyPress-s>", self.update)
        window.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>", self.update)
        # window.bind_all("<KeyPress-x>", self.deploy)

    def move(self, object, x, y):
        window.move(self.image, x, y)

    def update(self, event):

        if event.keysym == 'D':
            self.speed[1] = 1
            self.move(self.image, self.speed[0], 0)
        if event.keysym == "A":
            self.speed[1] = -1
            self.move(self.image, self.speed[0], 0)
        if event.keysym == "W":
            self.speed[0] = -1
            self.move(self.image, 0, self.speed[1])
        if event.keysym == "S":
            self.speed[0] = 1
            self.move(self.image, 0, self.speed[1])


    def deploy(self):
        pass
```

Here is the run point

```
while True:
    pl1 = Robot()
    pl1.update() # here is the problem
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Add `print(event.keysym)`, to see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you are using `time.sleep` which freezes tkinter's mainloop, preventing it to react to keyboard events. You don't need a `while True` loop, just execute your Tk instance's `mainloop`.

The second issue is that you are invoking the `Robot.update` method without passing the expected argument `event`. It is unnecessary to do it yourself, the keyboard bindings will trigger it each time one of the keys are pressed.

I think my answer to the question [Trying to make an object move in a grid with tkinter through player inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067129/trying-to-make-an-object-move-in-a-grid-with-tkinter-through-player-inputs/41078251#41078251) should help you.